# Realm : Results showing up as nil (either not saving or not writing)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, realm

Here is my Dog.Swift file:

```
import RealmSwift

class Dog : Object {

dynamic var name : String = ""
dynamic var age : Int8 = 0
}
```

and here is my where I'm making calls to it:

```
    let realm = Realm()

    var myDog = Dog()
    myDog.name = "Fido"
    myDog.age = 5

    realm.write{
        realm.add(myDog)
    }


    let documentsPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as! NSString

    let realmPath = documentsPath.stringsByAppendingPaths(["Dogs.swift"])
    let pathToFile = realmPath[0] as! String

    let allDogs = Realm(path: pathToFile).objects(MetricR)
    println(allDogs)
    println(allDogs.count)
```

Which outputs to the console:

```
Results<MetricR> (
)
0
```

So part 1 of my question : I added the documentsPath, realmPath, and pathToFile variables because earlier, when I was simply passing in "Dogs.swift" instead of pathToFile to the query, I was getting an error that said:

```
"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'open() failed: Permission denied
Unable to open a realm at path 'Dogs.swift'. Please use a path where your app has read-write permissions.'",
```

after which I changed the permissions of the file to 777, which did nothing, so I passed in the pathToFile variable instead which seemed to solve that problem.  I'm guessing ( I hope someone here can tell me!) , that that is related to the issue I'm having - which leads to part two - why is the query not resulting in anything?  Is it not saving, or not querying correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Disclaimer: I work for Realm)*

I think I'm seeing a few things there that might be causing some of those issues.

1) When you're adding that Dog object to Realm, you're using the `Realm()` object, which (by default, unless you change it) will be pointing to a Realm file named `default.realm` in your Documents directory. You'll need to specify the path to the `Dogs` Realm file when adding those objects, as well as reading.

2) That's correct. You need to specify the absolute file path to the Realm file you in which you want to save. If you just specify the file name, it's assuming you mean the root of your iOS device, which is out of your app's sandbox.

You should be able to set up the file path by getting your app's Documents file path as you did, but then calling `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` to add the file name to the end.

Also, it might be better to call the file `Dogs.realm` instead of `Dogs.swift`. It probably doesn't make a difference on the implementation, but would be less confusing.

3) When querying for the dogs objects, you've got an object called `MetricR` in there. Is that intentional? (It should simply be `Dog`).

Let me know if you require further clarification! Thanks!

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much!  I just passed in the path to Realm() and it's working now! I really appreciate your  help :)

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear you got it working! Thanks a lot for that! :) Let me know if you need help with anything else! :)

Comment: Actually quick follow up - So if I'm using multiple objects, do I keep passing in a different path for realm every time I instantiate a new Realm()?  For instance, realm = Realm(dogPath) for when I'm doing anything to the dog objects, and realm = Realm(ownerPath) for when I'm doing stuff to the owner objects?

Comment: No worries! Yeah, you Certainly can do that, but that means both owners and dogs will be saved to two completely separate Realm files on disk. Unless there's a specific technical reason, it might be easier to just save everything to a single Realm file. :)

Comment: Okay! So does that mean I should put all my classes in the same file??

Comment: I think by default, yes, you should. There might be cases where you might need to divide the data into separate Realm files for technical reasons, but until you actually have a reason, it'll be a lot less complexity to save all the classes to one file. :)